# See the number of new rows added to PostGRES tables each day

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I see the number of new rows added to each of my database's tables in the past day?

**Example result:**

```
table_name    new_rows
----------    -----------
users         32
questions     150
answers       98
...
```

I'm not seeing any table that stores this information in PostGRES statistics collector: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/monitoring-stats.html

The only solution I can think of, is create a database table that stores the row_count of each table at midnight each day.

**Edit**: I need this to work with any table, regardless of whether it has a "created_at" or other timestamp column. Many of the tables I would like to see the growth rate in, do not have timestamps columns & can't have one added.

Comment: Keep a `CreatedAt` column in each table, so you can see when rows were inserted.

Comment: I'd like it to work on every table, even if it doesn't have a timestamps column. A lot of our join tables don't have timestamps, I'm assuming because it would unnecessarily increase their size.

Comment: Your solution with nightly counts is straight-forward and should be OK. Alternatively, you can add an after insert trigger for each table that you want to monitor and update the stats as the data changes. It may be an overkill, though.

Comment: What would be the performance effects of an "insert trigger"? I've never used one, and I'm not sure what I would need to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a column in your table that keep a track of the insert/updated date.

Then to retrieve the rows, you can do a simple `select` for the last day.

From my knowledge, and I've also done a couple research to make sure, there is no intern functionality that allow you to do that without creating a field.

Comment: Thanks Jean-François, I'll keep that in mind :) For the moment I'm looking for a solution that would work without adding a field to tables.

Comment: You're welcome. However, I highly doubt someone will have a solution without adding a field. Still, I would be happy to read it.